# Find the general term of the alternating sequence $2, -5, 8, -11, 14$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the general term of the alternating sequence: $$2, -5, 8, -11,14$$

Comment: It is not a well-defined question. This pattern-seeking problem should be generally avoided.

Answer (score 3):

Your general term is $$a_n=(-1)^{n+1}(3n-1)$$

Note that $a_1=2, a_2=-5,...$